# Bash: immediately disown job after it is started (Bash inbuilt equivalent of Z Shell's &!)

Tags: bash, zsh

Is there a Bash equivalent of Z Shell's `&!` (or `&|`), i.e., immediately disown a job after it is started? I looked in Bash Reference Manual and searched in Google but can't seem to find anything relevant.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question title reads `immediately disown job after it is started`, but in the comment to Sirex's answer you write: `This question is not about how to disown a job immediately`. So, what is your question? Is something like `sleep 20 & disown` or `(sleep 20 &)` a solution to your problem? BTW what is your goal, that we don't run into another [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @mpy Simple. Bash **equivalent** of zsh `&!` or `&|`. Basically yes no answer. "This question is not about how to disown a job immediately" means I'm not interested in practical solutions because I know plenty. Maybe I should close this by now since I suppose the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nohup <cmd>` should do the job for you

Comment: This question is not about how to disown a job immediately (I know how to do that, and I could put the `disown` on the same line and achieve essentially the same effect), but rather, if this is a feature of Bash (and if so, how). `nohup` is a third party command, and it's certainly not a "Bash equivalent of Z Shell's `&!`".

Comment: oh right. no, it's not a part of bash (that i know of).

Comment: Also, `nohup` redirects stdout and stderr to file if they are connected to a tty, so that's definitely not equivalent.

Comment: "no, it's not a part of bash (that i know of)." That's also what I thought. Just to make sure.

Comment: yeah, but you can just redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do in practice. Just saying they are not equivalent from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: I'm accepting this because I suppose the answer is no. Getting this question out of the unanswered queue.